# 2 аккаунта разработчика и один аккаунт в адмобе

Tags: android, admob, google-adsense

Не заблокируют ли за такое?

- первый аккаунт принадлежит ООО, в котором работаю
- второй аккаунт лично мой.
- есть лично мой адмоб аккаунт.

И так получилось, что я встроил свою рекламу из личного адмоба в приложении компании и в свои личные приложения и залил их, соответственно, в разные акк ..

Не будет ли проблем из-за этого? Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет. Ранее делал подобное и проблем не возникало. Главное не нарушать условия публикации приложений, так как после блокировки аккаунта разработчика адмоб оставляет себе деньги